# JPA/Hibernate in Java SE 6, Best Practices for data access

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am starting a normal Java SE project and i am planning to use JPA/Hibernate. I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me as to what is considered the best way to interact with Hibernate in this environment (data access layers)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what's considered the best approach to this, but at my workplace, we have based most of our Hibernate interaction on these articles:

[Don't let Hibernate steal your identity](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html)
and [Generic Data Access Objects](http://www.hibernate.org/328.html)

They show you how to make your mapped classes in a smart way, and how to implement a generic DAO that can be reused for any persistent class. This has worked out nicely for us.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the guide for using [JPA with Hibernate](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2009/08/06/hibernate-tutorial-continued-using-annotations/)

We have used this approach in our application 1.5 years back and I do not think there is anything new in SE6 related to this.
We have worked with JDK 5 with heavily used annotations.