# Java Data Access

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm attempting to leverage better separation of our modules on a legacy project.  Before I get too deep into this, I want to ensure that [this](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects) is still the generally accepted way to handle Hibernate DAOs.

We are utilizing Spring MVC, as I understand it the practice is to inject our services into the controllers, and the DAOs into the services which rely upon them.

I saw this question: [JPA & Hibernate Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305436/jpa-hibernate-in-java-se-6-best-practices-for-data-access), but it was asked quite some time ago.  Is this still the typical way to layer Java EE projects or has a new methodology been born?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the typical approach. And it works fine.

It's not necessarily the best one, as many domain-driven design advocates will advise you, but that's a longer discussion (where to inject repositories (daos)). So for now - stick with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what else you'd do, particularly inside Spring where it's so well-supported. (With the caveat that Spring isn't really Java EE.) It makes things easy to test, easy to extend and modify, etc.

Now I'm curious, though, since other than "things that get the data", "things that do something with the things that get the data", and "things that use the results of the things that use the data getters" I'm not sure what other explicit layers make a lot of sense.